# LINQ-to-Json or String-to-Json

Tags: json, linq, parsing

I need to parse the json string at the bottom so that the sub-string representing the third level child

```
,"Media":{"ImageName":"Winter Twinkle"}
```

is removed.

Original JSON:

```
[{
    "BusinessID"   : 1,
    "BusinessName" : "Artland Painters",
    "Category" : {
                    "ClassificationAlias" : "beauty-art",
                    "ClassificationName"  : "Beauty Art",
                    "Media"               : {
                                              "ImageName":"Winter Twinkle"
                                            }
                  }
}]
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use e.g. [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) for this. First create an object from your json (I'm relying on the json snippet you provided):

```
var obj = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

Then iterate through your object, find the `Category` property, and its last child:

```
var media = obj.Select(t => t["Category"].Last);
```

Then remove the nodes found:

```
foreach (var item in media)
    item.Remove();
```

And, finally, serialize the object into a string:

```
var repairedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

This will give you the next result:

```
[{"BusinessID":1,"BusinessName":"Artland Painters","Category":{"ClassificationAlias":"beauty-art","ClassificationName":"Beauty Art"}}]
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. The method you are suggesting prompted me to think that I should state the original problem. And the original problem is to parse any object to JSON to the second complex object deep.  Media field will not be included as such. I will not know the names of the properties, unless I apply reflection, but that would add another operation. Is there a direct way to parse an object into JSON serializing first level properties and the second if they are simple, third level and deeper are excluded entirely. Thank you.

Comment: @itisinteresting, I'm afraid you'd have to write your own `JsonConverter` in this case